# What are ways to earn permanent double XP in Gears of War Judgement?

Tags: gears-of-war-judgment

I noticed here that you can earn permanent double XP if you purchase the  [season pass](http://www.gamestop.com/xbox-360/dlc/gears-of-war-judgment-vip-season-pass-xbox-360-live-marketplace-1600-points/108150?cid=eml_10000840) for GoW Judgement via GameStop.

I already purchased my season pass for this game, but I did it through Xbox Live...**Are there any other ways of obtaining or purchasing permanent double xp?**

I know you can purchase double XP per game via GoW Judgement's DLC but that is only limited to a specific game count (EX: 200 games for 800 Microsoft points, [other smaller game packs for less], etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't let the wording on GameStop's website fool you: there is only one season pass.  It doesn't matter whether you buy it from them, or on Xbox Live.

The only (current) ways to obtain double XP are:

- By purchasing the season pass and playing in the VIP playlist
- By purchasing X amount of double XP games in the marketplace

**Note:** Combining these two methods will result in 4 times the XP.

Comment: Oh so if I purchased this via GameStop I would get access to VIP (which I already have access to since I bought the season pass) ??

Comment: If you bought the season pass on Xbox Live, you already have what GameStop is selling you.  I think the original season pass was advertised as "permanent double xp", but what it really turned out to be is a playlist where xp is doubled (the VIP list).